# Bukkit coding help sender

Tags: java, bukkit

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
    Player player = player.getPlayer();
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("StaffWand")) {
        if(!sender.hasPermission("StaffWand.staff")) {
               sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Only Staff can use this!");
        if(sender.hasPermission("StaffWand.staff")) {
            sender.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "Here is your staff wand!")
            ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.STICK);
              sender.getInventory.addItem(item);
```

the sender.getInventory part is underlined red? Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This is a 101 object oriented programming question. I would suggest picking up a book and making sure I understand the fundamentals first!

Comment: I personally recommend "Beginning Java" by Ivor Horton, but any other book along these lines will be very beneficial to you.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `sender.getInventory()` is underlined in red is because there is no method `getInventory()` for the class `CommandSender`.

But the `Player` class does have the `getInventory()` method, so all you need to do is check to make sure that the `sender` is a `Player` then you can perform the `getInventory()` method.

To check if the `sender` is a `Player` you use the [`instanceof`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) keyword

e.g.

```
if (sender instanceof Player)
```

then in order to actually perform `getInventory()` you will need to do something called "[Casting](https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/java-cast/)".  All casting really means is taking an Object of one particular type and “turning it into” another Object type.

for e.g. to cast the sender to a Player you do

```
Player player = (Player) sender;
```

Note: Only cast if you have checked that the Object is an instance of what you are casting it to, or you will get at `InvalidCastException`.

So now to put all this together and to perform the `getInventory()` method you would do something like:

```
if (sender instanceof Player) {
    Player player = (Player) sender;
    Inventory inv = player.getInventory();

    //Do what you want to do with the inventory

}
```